# Enumerations, enhanced for loop

Tags: java, enums

Say I have `enum` values:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

Using the enhanced for loop construct, how can I write a code fragment that prints all the days of the week. I'm new to enhanced for loops so i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use for loop to iterate over all enum constants.

```
for (Day day : Day.values()) {

    //your code
    //Use variable "day" to access each enum constant in the loop.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**enhanced for loop construct**

> The enhanced for-loop is a popular feature introduced with the Java SE
>   platform in version 5.0. Its simple structure allows one to simplify
>   code by presenting for-loops that visit each element of an
>   array/collection without explicitly expressing how one goes from
>   element to element.

```
 for(Day days: Day.values()){

      System.out.println(days); // printing days
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is :

```
for (Day day : Day.values()) {
    System.out.println(day);
}
```